# How to randomly select from an input in python

Tags: python

```
N=input()       #Ex DOG,CAT,MIX,SUN,ELF
print(random.choice(N))
```

What came out was only a letter, how can i get a whole word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.choice` treats the input as a list of characters.
If  you want a random word use this:

```
import random
N=input().split(",")
print(random.choice(N))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
import random

N=input('write some words: ')       #Ex DOG,CAT,MIX,SUN,ELF
N = N.split(' ')    # split the input words into a list

print(random.choice(N))
```